# У меня есть бесконечный вывод который мне надо обрабатывать с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть бесконечный вывод который мне надо обрабатывать(прилагаю скриншот), мне надо вычленять то, что выводится в скобках text и обрабатывать это в последующем скрипте на python, как мне это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перенаправляете вывод первого скрипта во второй (`python script1.py | python script2.py`), во втором скрипте в бесконечном цикле читаете что приходит в sys.stdin, обрабатываете как вам нужно.

Comment: python script1.py | python script2.py это команда? и как вычленять именно то что находиться после text?

Comment: Это команда. Вычленять либо регулярными выражениями, либо читать построчно, пробовать декодировать как json, потом работать как со словарем.